# Get nil:NilClass from Rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I render the  `@navigation_months` in the view.

it works at the first time execution, but failed in the following tries.

How could I fix the error

## snippet

```
  Rails.cache.fetch(_get_cache_key, expires_in: EXPIRE[:general]) {
    @navigation_months = get_navigation_by_month  
  }
```

I can write my code in the format,

and it works .

But it seems ugly to my

```
  @navigation_months = Rails.cache.fetch(_get_cache_key, expires_in: EXPIRE[:general]) {
    get_navigation_by_month  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet the `@navigation_months` is not retrieved from the cache it's always retreived from the method `get_navigation_by_month`, the result of the block is stored in the cache but you're not using it.

From the documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching)

> This method does both reading and writing to the cache. When passed only a single argument, the key is fetched and value from the cache is returned. If a block is passed, the result of the block will be cached to the given key and the result is returned.

While in the second snipped you're using the result from `fetch` so `@navigation_months` is retrieved from the cache